# How to create two variables that rely on each other and on other values from a data frame?

Tags: r

I have a data frame with the next format:

```
trial <- c(1:4)
alpha <- rep(0.2, 4)
beta <- rep (0.5, 4)
df<- cbind.data.frame(trial, alpha, beta)
```

I need to create to variables `v` and `delta_v`. `delta_v <- alpha * (beta - v)`. `v` starts at 0 and for the next trials is based on the previous value of `v` and `delta_v` being the sum of them (v= v(previous trial) + delta_v (previous trial).

The output for this minimal example should be as a data frame:

```
trial <- c(1:4)
alpha <- rep(0.2, 4)
beta <- rep (0.5, 4)
v <- c(0, 0.1, 0.18, 0.244)
delta_v <- c(0.1, 0.08, 0.064, 0.0512)
df<- cbind(trial, alpha, beta, v, delta_v)
```

I am not of how to create a for loop for two variables that rely on each other and one of them starts at 0 and is computed based on i-1 values of the same variable and a another one that relies on it.

Many thanks!

Comment: in base R `lag()` and data.table `shift()` will help you doing this.

Comment: @abhiieor I think you mean `lag` from `dplyr` (rather than base R).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I will redo `df`, there is no need for `cbind`.

```
trial <- 1:4
alpha <- rep(0.2, 4)
beta <- rep (0.5, 4)
df <- data.frame(trial, alpha, beta)
```

Now, the code.
Start by defining an axilliary variable, `n`, and the variables of interest, `v` and `delta_v` outside the `for` loop. Then it's a matter of populating them.

```
n <- nrow(df)
v <- delta_v <- numeric(n)
delta_v[1] <- alpha[1]*(beta[1] - v[1])
for(i in seq_len(n)[-1]){
  v[i] <- v[i - 1] + delta_v[i - 1]
  delta_v[i] <- alpha[i]*(beta[i] - v[i])
}

v
#[1] 0.000 0.100 0.180 0.244
delta_v
#[1] 0.1000 0.0800 0.0640 0.0512

df <- data.frame(trial, alpha, beta, v, delta_v)
```

Comment: Oh wow, Thanks @Rui Barrandas !!! Could you explain me the logic behind v <- delta_v <- numeric(n) ? I can't figure out why numeric(n) is 0..

Comment: From the docs "numeric is identical to double (and real). It creates a double-precision vector of the specified length with each element equal to 0"

Comment: @AdelaIliescu Like RyanD explained `numeric(n)` creates a vector of `n` zeros. The point is to have memory space reserved and assign the computed values to those memory places. R can extend automatically a vector but that would take more in time each iteration.